Smart Keyboard Folio on iPad Air 6th Gen.?
I have an iPad Air 4th generation, and was considering upgrading to the new 6th generation that was just announced.  However, I noticed that Apple is no longer selling the Smart Folio Keyboard for iPad Air, and the Magic Keyboard is too big (and expensive) to justify it.  Does anyone know if the Smart Keyboard Folio that worked on the 4th generation iPad Air will work on the latest models?

If no one has these to try, Apple sales team will surely get you an answer online or over the phone if you inquire about it. This is a totally legitimate pre-sales question they are staffed to answer.

The MacRumors roundup article would suggest that it will work:

Compared to the 2022 model, Apple has introduced no major design
changes in 2024 ...
Like the iPad Pro, the iPad Air supports the $129 Apple Pencil Pro and
it works with the prior-generation $299 Magic Keyboard with trackpad
that Apple offers, but not the new model designed for the iPad Pro. It
is also compatible with the Smart Keyboard Folio and Smart Folio
covers, with these accessories connecting via the Smart Connector.

.. but as ever, I would definitely check in an Apple Store -- take your old keyboard and ask to try it on a new iPad. Apple does have a tendency to make tiny changes that render things incompatible!
